# react js placing context menu inside svg elements not rendering

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm new to react js and i'm doing a project to display floor maps using svgs. I added context menu using
React Contextmenu library. when I place the context menu it stops displaying the rectangles of the floor.

I followed the instructions in this article. [text](https://medium.com/how-to-react/create-a-context-menu-in-react-js-d30732bade6a)

```
 <svg  width="1000" height="1000" onMouseMove={handleMouseMove} onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}> 
                {floorData.map((floor, index) => (
                  <>
                    <ContextMenuTrigger  key={floor.id} id={`floor-${floor.id}`}>
                      <g key={floor.id}>
```

when I place **ContextMenuTrigger** outside of the **svg element** it renders properly using the JSON objcet and displays the context menu. Problem arises when I move the **ContextMenuTrigger** inside floorData.map((floor, index) functions since i need separate context menus for floors and blocks and clusters. This stops displaying floor svgs but shows blocks and clusters. what causes this issue and how to solve this?

```
return(
      <>
        <div>
          <h1>Loaded SVG</h1>
          <svg  width="1000" height="1000" onMouseMove={handleMouseMove} onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}> 
                {floorData.map((floor, index) => (
                  <>
                    <ContextMenuTrigger  key={floor.id} id={`floor-${floor.id}`}>
                      <g key={floor.id}>
                        <rect
                          key={`rect-${floor.id}`}
                          x={10}
                          y={30}
                          width={floor.width}
                          height={floor.height}
                          fill="lightblue"
                          opacity="1"
                        />
                        <text
                          x={floor.width / 2}
                          y={30 - 10} // Adjust the vertical position as needed
                          textAnchor="middle"
                          fill="black"
                          fontWeight="bold"
                        >
                          {floor.name}
                        </text>
                      </g> 
                    </ContextMenuTrigger>  
                    <ContextMenu id={`floor-${floor.id}`}>
                      <MenuItem data={{copy: floor.name}} onClick={copyCoupon}>
                          <FaRegCopy className="copy"/>
                          <span>Copy</span>
                      </MenuItem>
                      <MenuItem > 
                      {/* <MenuItem  onClick={(e) => handleMouseDown(e, `${block.floor_id}-${block.id}`)}> */}
                          <IoIosResize className="resize"/>
                          <span>Resize</span>
                      </MenuItem>
                      <MenuItem>
                        <RiDeleteBin6Line className="delete"/>
                        <span>Delete</span>
                      </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                  </>
                  
            ))}
              {/* load block*/ }
              {console.log(blockDataElement)}
              {blockDataElement.map((block, index) => (
                
                <g key={`group-${block.floor_id}-${block.id}`}>
                  
                    <g key={block.id}>
                      <rect
                        id={block.floor_id+'-'+block.id}
                        key={block.id}
                        x={block.x}
                        y={block.y}
                        width={block.width}
                        height={block.height}
                        fill="orange"
                        opacity="1"
                        onMouseDown={(e) => handleMouseDown(e, `${block.floor_id}-${block.id}`)}
                        
                      />
                      <text
                        x={block.x+block.width / 2}
                        y={block.y-10} // Adjust the vertical position as needed
                        textAnchor="middle"
                        fill="black"
                        fontWeight="bold"
                      >
                        {block.name}
                      </text>
                    </g>   
              </g>
              ))}
              {/* load cluster*/ }
              {console.log(clusterDataElement)}
              {clusterDataElement.map((cluster, index) => (
                <g key={cluster.id}>
                  <rect
                    id={`${cluster.floor_id}-${cluster.block_id}-${cluster.id}`}  //1-2-3 dash  get block here 
                    key={cluster.id}
                    x={cluster.x}
                    y={cluster.y}
                    width={cluster.width}
                    height={cluster.height}
                    fill="green"
                    opacity="1"
                    onMouseDown={(e) => handleMouseDown(e, `${cluster.floor_id}-${cluster.block_id}-${cluster.id}`)}
                  />
                  <text
                    x={cluster.x+cluster.width / 2}
                    y={cluster.y-10} // Adjust the vertical position as needed
                    textAnchor="middle"
                    fill="black"
                    fontWeight="bold"
                  >
                    {cluster.name}
                  </text>
                </g> 
              ))}
              
              {/* load seats*/ }
              {seatData.map((seat, index) => (
                <g key={`group-${seat.floor_id}-${seat.block_id}-${seat.cluster_id}-${seat.id}`}>
                  <image
                    id={`${seat.floor_id}-${seat.block_id}-${seat.cluster_id}-${seat.id}`} 
                    key={seat.id}
                    x={seat.x} 
                    y={seat.y} 
                    width="30" 
                    height="30" 
                    href={chairIcon}
                  />
                  <text
                    id={`text-${seat.floor_id}-${seat.block_id}-${seat.cluster_id}-${seat.id}`} 
                    x={seat.x}
                    y={seat.y-10} // Adjust the vertical position as needed
                    textAnchor="middle"
                    fill="black"
                    
                  >
                    {seat.name}
                  </text>
                </g> 
              ))}
          </svg>  
        </div>
      </>
    );
```